# POI 3.17 NPE while retrieving ClientAnchor from CellComment

Tags: java, apache-poi, comments

While trying to copy CellComments from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook, the retrieval of the CellComment ClientAnchor receives an NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment.getClientAnchor(XSSFComment.java:220)
```

Code Used:

```
for (Entry<CellAddress, ? extends Comment> e : sheet.getCellComments().entrySet())
  {
    CellAddress addr = e.getKey();
    Comment comment = e.getValue();
    ClientAnchor anchor = comment.getClientAnchor();
```

Is this an issue of POI or the retrieval code?

Note that the below code works and retrieves the ClientAnchor.

```
  for (CellAddress addr : sheet.getCellComments().keySet())
  {
    Comment comment = sheet.getCellComment(addr);
    ClientAnchor anchor = comment.getClientAnchor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a issue of `apache poi`, at least with `apache poi` version `3.17`. And the kind of issue is one of the reasons why I am not on `apache poi`' s developer list.

All the following is about  `apache poi` version `3.17`.

If [XSSFComment.java:220](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFComment.java?view=markup#l220) throws NPE, then `_vmlShape` is `null`. So what is `_vmlShape`? It is a `com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape` which normally is set in `XSSFComment`'s constructor.

[public XSSFComment(CommentsTable comments, CTComment comment, CTShape vmlShape)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFComment.java?view=markup#l50).

So why can this be `null` in a value of an `Entry` of  `XSSFSheet.getCellComments().entrySet()`?

In `XSSFSheet` [public Map getCellComments()](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l839) returns `sheetComments.getCellComments()`. So what is `sheetComments`? It is a `org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CommentsTable` which was read while [reading the sheet's package part from the worbook](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l224).

So what returns `sheetComments.getCellComments()`? It returns a [`final TreeMap<CellAddress, XSSFComment> map`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/CommentsTable.java?view=markup#l158) where each value is a `XSSFComment`. But all those `XSSFComment`s are new constructed having `CTShape vmlShape` = `null`: `map.put(e.getKey(), new XSSFComment(this, e.getValue(), null));`.

Well, thats why `_vmlShape` was `null` and  `XSSFComment.java` code line 220 had thrown NPE.

And why `sheet.getCellComment(addr)` works having `addr` a `CellAddress` got as a key of the same `TreeMap<CellAddress, XSSFComment>`?

Well because there the programmers had known about the necessity of the `VMLDrawing`, see  [public XSSFComment getCellComment(CellAddress address)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l814).

Comment: I assume the POI developers are aware of this issue? or should a bug be added to their tracker?

Comment: @Ed Holland: You can file a bug. But since `sheet.getCellComment` works, what do you think is the advantage of getting the `Comment` from `sheet.getCellComments` `Entry` instead?